# Looking for a series of books that starts with a girl looking in her fridge, realizing she doesn’t like what’s in there and switches it

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

She switches it with her friends, who I think is a boy. I remember it had something about her dad being poor so their fridge was pretty bare, but her friends parents had money so his fridge was full.

I also remember a part where they travel to a different planet and the sun is about to explode. They meet a young prince who has magic powers too but never uses them because he is saving his magic energy to save the planet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read these books?  Where were they set?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Answer (score 13):

[Wizard's Holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard%27s_Holiday), book seven of the [Young Wizards series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Wizards) by Diane Duane.

In book five, [The Wizard's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard%27s_Dilemma), Nita's mother dies of cancer, and the family keep forgetting to do grocery shopping. At the beginning of Wizard's Holiday Nita telepathically asks her partner Kit if she can switch the contents of their fridges briefly, so that she can get something to eat. (They are both teenagers, and his Mum always keeps loads of good stuff in their fridge.)

As you mention an exploding sun, this may be "Lifeboats", as they're invited to help move the population of the planet through portals to a safe place.

Comment: Which one of this series?

Comment: @Valorum  The OP is looking for a book series anyway.

Comment: I imagine the exploding sun memory is also of Wizard's Holiday, and they've simply misremembered that THE Sun is going to explode and it's convenient that Roshaun the sun-specialist wizard prince is on student exchange to Earth.